# Every time i run this code it gives me error saying "(CMTime) presentationTime = <out of scope>" and same with imageBufferRef out of scope

Tags: xcode, swift, avfoundation

Running the following code

```
var sampleData  = NSMutableArray()

for var i = sampleData.count-1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- {

        let  presentationTime : CMTime = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleData[i] as! CMSampleBuffer)

        let imageBufferRef : CVPixelBufferRef = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleData[sampleData.count - i - 1] as! CMSampleBuffer)!

        while (!writerInput.readyForMoreMediaData) {
            NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(0.1)
        }

        pixelBufferAdaptor.appendPixelBuffer(imageBufferRef, withPresentationTime: presentationTime)
 }
```

Yields the following error:

```
objc[1670]: _objc_rootFinalize called with garbage collection off

Printing description of imageBufferRef:
(CVPixelBufferRef) imageBufferRef = out of scope

Printing description of presentationTime:
(CMTime) presentationTime = out of scope
```

Comment: you fetch something from sampleData which you initialize new, lines before?

Comment: please post more code, this is clearly only an excerpt right?